# during client authentication in Keycloak. null value returned by getAuthenticationSession()

Tags: django, keycloak

I attempted to obtain a token from the Keycloak server using the password grant. However, after changing the user password and making some modifications to the authentication process, I encountered the following error:

I made an attempt to resolve the issue by restarting the Keycloak server, as well as restarting and modifying the grant, but unfortunately, the problem persists
2023-11-21 16:43:52,510 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-37) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=7ffc23bd-250e-429e-8026-14cff8c6bdef, clientId=Print_login_protect, userId=null, ipAddress=172.20.67.92, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, response_type=code, redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/home, code_id=40bf3e47-17b9-44f4-837b-508490fd71c9, response_mode=query
2023-11-21 16:45:41,979 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (executor-thread-36) KC-SERVICES0015: Unexpected error when authenticating client: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.keycloak.sessions.AuthenticationSessionModel.getExecutionStatus()" because the return value of "org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.getAuthenticationSession()" is null
at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.isProcessed(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:68)
at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.isProcessed(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:63)
at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processSingleFlowExecutionModel(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:373)
at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:249)
at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateClient(AuthenticationProcessor.java:897)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.utils.AuthorizeClientUtil.authorizeClient(AuthorizeClientUtil.java:50)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.checkClient(TokenEndpoint.java:269)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.processGrantRequestInternal(TokenEndpoint.java:217)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.processGrantRequest(TokenEndpoint.java:190)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:154)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:118)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:560)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:452)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:413)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:378)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:174)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:142)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:168)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:131)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:33)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:429)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:240)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:154)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:157)